# undefined reference to `__intel_sse4_atol' problem

Tags: cross-compilation, intel

I'm trying to build OpenFOAM for Xeon Phi, but I got an error as defined [here](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/135810-undefined-reference-__intel_sse4_atol.html)

```
icpc -std=c++0x -Dlinux64 -DWM_DP -wd327,525,654,819,1125,1476,1505,1572 -xHost -O2 -no-prec-div  -DNoRepository -I.. -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/transportModels/twoPhaseMixture/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/transportModels -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/transportModels/incompressible/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/transportModels/interfaceProperties/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/turbulenceModels/incompressible/turbulenceModel -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/meshTools/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/fvOptions/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/sampling/lnInclude -IlnInclude -I. -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed Make/linux64IccDPOpt/porousInterFoam.o -L/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib \
             -ltwoPhaseMixture -linterfaceProperties -ltwoPhaseProperties -lincompressibleTransportModels -lincompressibleTurbulenceModel -lincompressibleRASModels -lincompressibleLESModels -lfiniteVolume -lmeshTools -lfvOptions -lsampling -lOpenFOAM -ldl   -L/lib -lm -o /root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/bin/porousInterFoam
ld: warning: libimf.so, needed by /root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib/libtwoPhaseMixture.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libsvml.so, needed by /root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib/libtwoPhaseMixture.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libirng.so, needed by /root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib/libtwoPhaseMixture.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
ld: warning: libintlc.so.5, needed by /root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib/libtwoPhaseMixture.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/root/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/platforms/linux64IccDPOpt/lib/libtriSurface.so: undefined reference to `__intel_sse4_atol'
```

and I searched for libimf.so, and i found it here:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/compiler/lib/mic/libimf.so
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/compiler/lib/ia32/libimf.so
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/compiler/lib/mic/libimf.so
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/compiler/lib/ia32/libimf.so
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/compiler/lib/intel64/libimf.so
```

where should I put the `-rpath or -rpath-link` flag?

or should i run this command first?

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/bin/compilervars_arch.sh mic
```

Answer (score 1):

You should source the `bin/compilervars.sh` script before you do the compilation. This sets all the required environment variables.

Most important in your case is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which should contain a reference to the paths:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/compiler/lib/mic
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/compiler/lib/intel64"
```

The compilervars script will set this.

I wouldn't recommend setting `rpath` or `rpath-link` manually as this should not be necessary if you source the `compilervars.sh`.